# Risks involving DNS lookups at scale

Tags: dns

I have a use case that involves checking millions of DNS lookups (Mostly MX records)(around ~100 requests per sec)
What are the potential problems I can face (also regarding the cloud provider - AWS)
I know the DNS servers might throttle our requests

Is there a need to rotate the resolvers I use, use a proxy service,
and can will it seem suspicious by the cloud provider and might get my process blocked